# Netplan on Ubuntu 18.04 with multiple interfaces connected to internet

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, netplan, systemd-networkd

I am using `netplan` to configure the interfaces on Ubuntu 18.04, but there are a few issues. First, the `metric` does not seem to be working as it is set to 0. Second, once I use `networkd` the whole network seems to be down!

The set up is like:

```
                                  Internet                     Internet 
     (local-link)                    /                         /           
 Dev1               |-----|        |-----|      |-----|                   - Dev11 (192.168.0.5)
    ----------------| eno |        | tun |      | usb | ---- (AP) -------|
 Dev2               |_____|        |_____|      |_____|     192.168.0.1   - Dev12 (192.168.0.6)
 (172.168.0.6)      172.168.0.2               192.168.0.2 
                 
                |------------------PC ------------------|
```

The `YAML` file is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp60s1:
      match:
        macaddress: 3b:2d:x:x:x
      addresses: [192.168.0.2/24]
      dhcp4: no
      optional: true
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      set-name: usb
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1,8.8.8.8]
      mtu: 8192  
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.0.1
         metric: 50
         table: 101
      routing-policy:
       - from: 192.168.0.0/24
         table: 101
```

I was hoping to use `NetworkManager` but it does seem that non-default routes are not supported.
I then run

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
sudo service systemd-networkd restart
```

but `route -n` gives:

```
Destination   Gateway      Genmask         Flags     Metric  Ref   Use   Iface  
0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1   0.0.0.0          UG        0       0    0      usb
0.0.0.0      10.100.80.1   0.0.0.0          UG       20000    0    0      wlan
10.8.0.0     0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0    U         0       0    0      tun
10.100.80.0  0.0.0.0       255.255.248.0    U         600     0    0      wlan  
172.168.0.0  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0    U         0       0    0      eno
192.168.0.0  0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0    U         0       0    0      usb
```

and then the host (PC) becomes unreachable (remotely connected via `ssh`).

Why the `metric` is not set, since it is defined in `YAML` file? I want the Devs connected to the AP to have access to internet via the AP, hence I try `ping -w 1 8.8.8.8 -I usb` which results to 100% packet loss.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to set a static IP address to enp60s1. In the usual case you don't need to set all these fields. Have you tried the usual minimal configuration? https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: @StephenBoston I tried to have it as minimal as possible. First, with `networkd` the `metric` is not shown, as it does when `NetworkManager` is applied (up to `mtu` line). Also, I have two interfaces with two gateways, where packets from subnet 192.168 should reach the internet through the 192.168.0.1, and all others through a different interface. Now, it seems that 192.168.0.1 forwards packets to `tun` interface (lower metric), which is not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting both:

```
  gateway4: 192.168.0.1
```

and:

```
  routes:
   - to: 0.0.0.0/0
     via: 192.168.0.1
     metric: 50
     table: 101
```

`gateway4` is shorthand for a default route.  You should not combine the two.  This is almost certainly why your metric is being clobbered, because the `gateway4` setting is overriding.  A metric of 0 is not actually a problem since a metric of 0 has an even higher priority than one of 50, but all of your routing table settings would also be clobbered which is likely more the issue.

Comment: Ok, the `gateway4` has been removed. But still the `usb` interface has no internet access. The traffic from the Dev11, Dev12 should be forwarded to internet only through the AP. Shouldn't the `routing-policy:` be responsible for this (or should I update the route rules)?

Comment: I have managed somehow to replicate it locally. I have connected two routers on diff interf (i.e. `eno1` and `usb1`), both connected to internet. I tried with `renderer: NetworkManager` up to the `mtu` line, and from `route -n` and `ip r` I could see that there were two default gateways with 100 and 101 metric. `ping` Google worked through the interfaces, but when I `traceroute` it seems that the traffic from the `usb1` goes though the gateway in `eno1` and reaches the final dest. `traceroute` on `eno1` goes up to 1 hop and then no information. With `networkd` the metric isnt shown.

Comment: 101 as a metric?  The yaml in your question doesn't show a metric of 101 anywhere, only a routing table id of 101.  Please make sure you're showing the full config that corresponds to the output you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

[Connecting multiple interfaces with DHCP](https://netplan.io/examples/#connecting-multiple-interfaces-with-dhcp)
:
"One can achieve the exact routing desired over DHCP by specifying a metric for the routes retrieved over DHCP, which will ensure some routes are preferred over others. In this example, ‘enred’ is preferred over ‘engreen’, as it has a lower route metric:"

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        enred:
            dhcp4: yes
            dhcp4-overrides:
                route-metric: 100
        engreen:
            dhcp4: yes
            dhcp4-overrides:
                route-metric: 200
```