# Ubuntu 18.04 route delete permanently

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, iptables

I want to delete a route permanently on Ubuntu 18.04.

The route is the following,`route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags  Metric   Ref    Use    Iface
 ...            ...                ...           ...    ...     ...    ...     ...
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U       1000     0      0      eno1
```

after the `sudo route del -net 169.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0` or `sudo ip route del 169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1` the route is not listed in `route -n` and `ip r`.

However, the route rule is showing again after `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply`. This rule might be the leftover from an old configuration, which it doesn't exist now. I checked if there is anything connected with `sudo arp-scan --interface=eno1 169.254.0.0/16`  and there were no devices. None of the `YAML` files in `/etc/netplan` list an 169.254.x.x IP.

Also, I checked the `/etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d` as I had applied some rules, but still no indication of an 169.254.x.x.

Is there a specific file where the rules are retrieved/cached?

Comment: That's a zeroconf route, added by `avahi-autoipd` iirc

Comment: It means that the entry is normal, right?

Comment: yes it's normal afaik - is there a specific issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, trying to have two gateways with different [rules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250604/netplan-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-multiple-interfaces-connected-to-internet) and stumbled upon this route rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route `169.254.0.0/16` is called zeroroute.
It is added automatically when you reboot your system. You can disable it in network configuration.

```
sudo nano /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Add below line in network configuration file.

```
NOZEROCONF=yes
```

Restart networking service.

```
sudo systemctl restart networking.service
```

Comment: Wow! Impressive.

Comment: I wouldn't say so. It's a commercial PC box with a clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04. Everything runs locally, there is no connection or account to AWS EC2 service. In any case, good to know that.

Comment: Are you using static ip address ?

Comment: @KKPatel yes, I am using a static IP. I suppose then it does not do any harm of having it right? I want to set some rules and I thought that it was from another configuration.

Comment: Configuring Nozeroconf=yes in network configuration will work.